# In Haskell, how can get the filename without the file extension?

Tags: haskell

Say I have a filename (a list of characters):

```
"myfile.xml"
```

How can I get:

```
"myfile"
```

?

Comment: Don't you mean all but the last *four* elements?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In case you want to eliminate the extension, I propose to use a library like [**`System.FilePath.Posix`**](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/filepath-1.4.1.2/docs/System-FilePath-Posix.html#v:takeBaseName):

```
import System.FilePath.Posix(takeBaseName)
```

Then you can use the `takeBaseName` function to obtain the basename of a filename:

```
Prelude> import System.FilePath.Posix(takeBaseName)
Prelude System.FilePath.Posix> takeBaseName "myfile.xml"
"myfile"
```

This solution works better, since it will also work on `"file.gz"` and `"foo.7z"`.